# Why does image constructed by createObjectURL have 0 width?

Tags: javascript

This is my code which is supposed to load an image from a **form file input** and resize it if it is too large. The problem is that when I create a new image object and set its src, its width equals to zero. However when I put the image into html it display correctly.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
var image_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(image_data);
image.src = image_url;
console.log('Width: ' + image.width);
```

-> Width: 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment you set the src, the image starts loading, but it's not yet loaded when you request the width. Use the onload event to fix that:

```js
var image = document.createElement('img');
var image_url = "http://domaingang.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/example.png"; //window.URL.createObjectURL(image_data);
image.src = image_url;
image.onload = function()
{
  alert(image.width);
}
```