# Image does not load properly

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a simple page im HTML/javascript. The point is to check some parameters (width, height...) of an image that the user submit a form. In JS i get the file from the form, and try to "convert" it to an image using Object URL.

Problem happens there, when i load the url into the image `.src` property, the image does not seem to load well. Its attributes keep the default values (width=0, name =""...) and the `.onload` event isn't even triggered.

A simplified version of my code is below.

The url works well when i copy/paste it in my browser I get the image I submited. Neither the `.onload` or `.onerror` function is called.

I don't get why the image isn't loaded properly. If anyone has a clue I'll be glad if you share it.

```js
function checkData() {
  var images = document.getElementsByName('img');

  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    alert('the image is drawn');
  }

  img.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("Not ok", e);
  }

  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(images[0].files[0]);

  if (img.width != 385 || img.height != 345) {
    alert("Wrong size");
    return false;
  }
}

console.log();
```

```html
<form method=POST name="Form" onsubmit="return checkData()" action="">
  Image 1
  <input type="file" name="img"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="check">

</form>
```

Comment: `width` and `height` won't be populated until `onload` is called, but you return from the function before that happens. Move the check into `onload` and you should be fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does image constructed by createObjectURL have 0 width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919847/why-does-image-constructed-by-createobjecturl-have-0-width)

Comment: Incidentally, the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ctx is not defined` indicates that the `onload` event is indeed fired.

Comment: Sorry about the undefined ctx, I just dumbly copy/pasted from the original code. I edited the code so this error doesn´t mess with the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will draw a user uploaded image to a canvas. I think that's what you're going for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST name="Form" action="">
    Image 1 
    <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</form>
<script>

    function previewFile() {
        var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (file) {
            ctx.drawImage(file,385,345);
        } 
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a duplicate, as mentioned in my comment.
But just out of curiosity, I built a working example below.

You must wait until the image loads before checking its dimensions.

```js
function checkData() {

  console.log('checking image size...');

  var img = new Image();
  var images = document.getElementsByName('img');
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

  img.onload = function() {

    if (img.width != 385 || img.height != 345) {
      console.log("Wrong size: " + img.width + " X " + img.height);
    } else {
      ctx.drawImage(this, 20, 20);
      console.log("The image is drawn.");
    }

  }

  img.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("Not ok", e);
  }

  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(images[0].files[0]);

}

var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkData();
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form" id="myform" action="">
  Image 1
  <input type="file" name="img"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="check">
</form>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: A big thank's ! Sorry I could not answer earlier but you got that perfectly. It was indeed that I returned from the function before the onload function finish. I will just folow your example and put the check into the onload function.